# Is there a way for a single item within an array to identify the very same array object that contains itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, if I have an array:

```
var myArr =[a,b,c];
```

Is there a way to do something like this,

```
a.someReferenceMethod = myArr?
```

Comment: Depends on what `a` is. If it is of primitive type then it's not possible. If it's an object it's possible to have circular reference of course. But you probably want it to be automatically then you are out of luck.

Comment: No, there isn’t, unless you assign one specifically, e.g. with `a.array = myArr;`, but that’s kind of a given, and won’t work on primitives like numbers, booleans, or strings, either. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there is a natively supported method that will return the parent array object back to each node within the array, I guess I'll just assign the array object itself as a property to each item within the array thru a for-loop or something, thanks all!

Comment: you can look for it in known arrays, but there is no intrinsic reflection.

Comment: @Hank: Just think of the situation `var arr1 = [a,b], arr2 = [a,c];`. Which array would be the parent of `a`? It's indeterminable.

Comment: @Bergi, very good point, ha! I'll just 'manually' assign the desired array to each item then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = {
myArray : [],
getArray : function(){return this.myArray},
setArray : function(array){this.myArray = array}
};
var myArr =[a, "test"];
a.setArray(myArr);
window.alert(myArr[0].getArray()[1]);
</script>
```

In this case calling the getArray() method of the first element in the array would return you the array itself...

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping I wouldn't have to do all that, LOL! Oh well, I guess there's a limit what JS can do.